# React - Set State after every forEach API Request has completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a block of code that looks like this.

```
data.forEach(driver => {
          wiki().page(`${driver.Driver.givenName} ${driver.Driver.familyName}`)
          .then(page => page.mainImage())
          .then(img => driver.image = img)
        })

        this.setState({
          drivers: data
        })
      })
```

So for each element in the array, it makes a call to an api and then adds a property to the `data` object. However, I also want to `setState` after all these async actions are complete and I don't know how to do it in a forEach loop. How can I do this?

Comment: Put it in a useEffect hook? Don’t classes very well....

Comment: You could use a `map` instead of `forEach` and map each data item out as a `Promise` (your already creating a promise in the `forEach`). Pass the resultant array to `Promise.all` which will wait for every `Promise` in the array to complete before resolving: `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(resultArray => { /* do some stuff */ });`

Comment: @JacobSmit I'm a bit new to `Promises`, I understand the `.all` part, but how am I supposed to assign them inside the `.map` function and return them exactly?

Comment: someone seems to have already put an example up as an answer, that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get an array of Promises, which you can then "wait for" with `.then`:

```
const promises = data.map(driver =>
  wiki().page(`${driver.Driver.givenName} ${driver.Driver.familyName}`)
  .then(page => page.mainImage())
);

Promise.all(promises).then(images => {
  const newData = data.map((driver, idx) => ({ ...driver, image: images[idx] }))
  this.setState({ data: newData });
});
```

Comment: I think your `then` in the `map` is missing the closing parentheses.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand the concept now, however now I am getting an unexpected token error on the spread operator. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: oops, sorry - it's a syntactic gotcha with arrow functions that return objects, that I've fallen into again (because I wasn't running the code for it to be caught). You just need to surround the object in parentheses. I'll edit.

Comment: and thanks for catching that error @JacobSmit - I've made both edits now

Comment: Got it! It works perfectly now, thank you so much!